Handling Nested JSON Field Searches in OpenSearch Serverless with Null Checks
I'm working on a project using Amazon OpenSearch Serverless to store and search content based on tags. Both tags to filter and tags of content can be multiple. Documents, or contents, may not contain any tag field, too. I need to filter and search content based on the similarity of tags between tags to filte and the content. Similarity is decided in this way: if a tag have the same group_id, then it should have the same id and src_code.
Example Structure:
Here is an example of the tags field in the content documents:
"_source": {
          "tags": [
            {
              "group_id": 5,
              "id": 1,
              "src_code": "2324"
            },
            {
              "group_id": 6,
              "id": 2,
              "src_code": "91"
            },
            {
              "group_id": 7,
              "id": 3,
              "src_code": "3124"
            },
            {
              "group_id": 8,
              "id": 4,
              "src_code": "5543"
            }
          ]
        }

Tags to filter:
{
  "filter_tags": [
    {"id": 123, "group_id": 1, "src_code": "2"},
    {"id": 124, "group_id": 2, "src_code": "23"},
    {"id": 1, "group_id": 5, "src_code": "2324"},
    {"id": 4, "group_id": 6, "src_code": "2325"},
  ]
}


The goal is to return documents where all filter_tags match the corresponding content tags based on group_id, id, and src_code. filter_tags may contains tags whose group_id is different than content, in that case I don't want to compare them.
With the given examples, I want to compare only 3rd and 4th filter_tags, since they content tags have the same group_id:
1st filter_tag -> don't compare since no matching group_id
2nd filter_tag -> don't compare since no matching group_id
3rd filter_tag -> compare since group_id matches -> score is 1 since id and src_code are equal.
4th filter_tag -> compare since group_id matches -> score is 0 since id and src_code are not equal.
Overall don't match the doc, since there is a tag with same group_id but different id and src_code.
What I have tried:
I tried the following two methods

Without tag field exists check

POST /bedrock-knowledge-base-default-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "tags",
            "query": {
              "function_score": {
                "query": {
                  "match_all": {}
                },
                "functions": [
                  {
                    "script_score": {
                      "script": {
                        "source": """
                          double score = 0;
                          for (def filter_tag : params.filter_tags) {
                            boolean match = false;
                            for (def content_tag : doc['tags']) {
                              if (content_tag['group_id'].value == filter_tag.group_id &&
                                  content_tag['id'].value == filter_tag.id &&
                                  content_tag['src_code'].value == filter_tag.src_code) {
                                match = true;
                                break;
                              }
                            }
                            if (match) {
                              score += 1;
                            } else {
                              score = 0;
                              break;
                            }
                          }
                          return score;
                        """,
                        "params": {
                          "filter_tags": [
                            {"id": 1, "group_id": 5, "src_code": "2324"},
                            {"id": 2, "group_id": 6, "src_code": "91"}
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "boost_mode": "replace"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": ["tags"]
}


The error I got:
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "runtime error",
        "script_stack": [
          "org.opensearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:82)",
          "org.opensearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:50)",
          "for (def content_tag : doc['tags']) {\n                              ",
          "                           ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script": " ...",
        "lang": "painless",
        "position": {
          "offset": 221,
          "start": 194,
          "end": 262
        }
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": []
  },
  "status": 400
}

I thought this is because some documents don't have tags field and added a condition to check the existence of the field:
POST /bedrock-knowledge-base-default-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "tags",
            "query": {
              "function_score": {
                "query": {
                  "match_all": {}
                },
                "functions": [
                  {
                    "script_score": {
                      "script": {
                        "source": """

                         # THIS IS THE ADDED CONDITION

                         if ((! doc.containsKey('tags') )|| doc['_source']['tags'].empty) {
                            return 0.8;
                          }



                          double score = 0;
                          for (def filter_tag : params.filter_tags) {
                            boolean match = false;
                            for (def content_tag : doc['tags']) {
                              if (content_tag['group_id'].value == filter_tag.group_id &&
                                  content_tag['id'].value == filter_tag.id &&
                                  content_tag['src_code'].value == filter_tag.src_code) {
                                match = true;
                                break;
                              }
                            }
                            if (match) {
                              score += 1;
                            } else {
                              score = 0;
                              break;
                            }
                          }
                          return score;
                        """,
                        "params": {
                          "filter_tags": [
                            {"id": 1, "group_id": 5, "src_code": "2324"},
                            {"id": 2, "group_id": 6, "src_code": "91"}
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "boost_mode": "replace"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": ["tags"]
}

But this time all of the documents, even those with tags field are returned with 0.8 score.
Asking for help for these cases

Correct Null Check: How can I correctly check for the presence and non-emptiness of the tags field in the script?
Correct Filtering: How can I filter tags based on my need: equal group id should have the equal id and src_code
Suggestions for Document Structure: If there isn't any way or easy way to achieve the goal, are there any recommended changes to the structure of my documents to make such queries more straightforward.

